# General questions regarding mobile development

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

I am working on iPhone app development currently (primarily native app using Obj-C and some web app using jQTouch). My question is regarding the future of this space;

1. In say 3 years time, what do you think would be preferred (native or web app) ?
2. What are the strengths going to be for native app (I know for certain types like Games, people prefer native than browser-based, but will that remain that way forever)
3. Some people say HTML5 will replace native app development, as it will be "code once, run anywhere" kind of thing (like common for iPhone, Android, BB phones). So do you think HTML5 can completely eliminate native app development.

I know the mobile space is constantly changing with new technologies coming up regularly and hence one cannot say with certainty what the situation will be 3 years forward. But I think there are projections being made by many agencies. So are there any reputed ones which can give a general idea or some sense of what might happen in future.

My main aim is what exactly should be my focus (like what technology/platform/native-web apps), if I want to look at the mobile space for the next 5-10 years.

Please provide as many responses as possible.

Comment: There really can't be a definitive answer to this, because none of us can tell the future.  Also, questions that promote extended discussion really aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2c.

1. The popularity of web based apps will continue to grow. Whether it will pass native apps I don't know. For them to be on par in terms of numbers in 3 years doesn't seem unrealistic.
2. Native apps have the following benefits:

   - Better performance (potentially)
   - Fewer restrictions on accessing device resources
   - Greater control of execution of application
3. HTML5 won't completely eliminate the need for native apps (see point 2 above). Even Google who are creating an entirely web based OS (ChromeOS) don't seem to be looking to get rid of Java/Dalvik for Android based dev.

"code once, run anywhere" is very unlikley for anything but the simplest of apps/functionality.
"Code once, compile for each supported platform then test everywhere" is much more realistic.

I'd recommend focusing your education on what makes a great mobile regardless of platform and looking at web based development.

Comment: Hi Matt..thanks for the response...Regarding the iphone native developmet, don't u think many people dislike the approval process (like lots of restrictions) and do u think Andrioid might overtake Apple in terms of no. of apps because of this ?

Comment: Nope. In the end, number of apps is irrelevant, as 99% of them will be total bullshit. Number of quality apps is what matters: iOS has a few quality apps, Android has none. That's what matters.

Comment: As Jonathan said, the total number of apps isn't a useful metric of quality or utility. It's just a nice thing for marketeers to have. The issue with the Apple approval process is inconsistency, not that there is one. In theory it raises the quality bar or at least stops the high number of malicious apps which are reportedly available for Android. The number of android apps is also, in part, down to the number and variety of Android devices available. As it becomes harder and harder to make an Android app which works with all Android phones, I think, it's likley to put more developers off.

Comment: I do agree with the points about quality being made by you. But do you think because of this point, Android might never make it bing in the "enterprise apps" segment, where BB and Apple might dominate? However one more point is Android might make improvements in the future and get good quality apps. In fact, many consumer apps are common to both Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

1: Native. It will always be preferred, as it is the most convenient type of app. Personally, I only have one web-app on my phone.

2: The iOS-framework. It is really the largest upside of the native apps. And the fact that they are easily downloadable through the App Store.